# Vue 3 - scrolling not possible. No scrollbar on browser

Tags: vue.js, scrollbar

I create with several v-for loops, some divs which are bigger that my screen. But there is no scrollbar on Firefox or Chrome. So they cut of my div and I can see just a part of the div.

Did I miss something on Vue?

[Lot of Data but no scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPDFi.jpg)

[Lot of data is fetched and stored in items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6tGH.jpg)

```
    <template>
  <div class="ChildAddItem">
      <div>Searchbar placeholder</div>
         <div class="ItemChoiche" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>{{item}}</td>
            </tr>

          </table>
        <p v-if="item == null">Null</p>
        
      <p>test</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data: () => ({
    openItemsearch: false,
    groupid: '',
    playerid: '',
    items: []    
    }),
mounted() {
   this.$axios.get("getallData").then((response) => (this.items = response.data));
   this.groupid = this.$route.params.group;
   this.playerid = this.$route.params.player;
  },
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: any luck on this? having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

resolved by remove the postion: fixed in the navigation bar css

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).